# Alternative for StringRelatedField

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get following user with their names instead of PrimaryKey, I tried to use StringRelatedField. It worked for GET request, but it does not allow to write. Could not find any alternatives for this. I want to get json result as this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": "admin",
    "following": "user_1"
}
```

I assume instead of using StringRelatedField I should redefine create in serializers, am I right?

[image]
[image]

model.py

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower'
    )
    following = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='following'
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['user', 'following'],
                name='unique_user_following'
            )
        ]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.following
```

serializer.py

```
class FollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugField(
        read_only=True,
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    # following = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'following',)

        validators = [
            serializers.UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Follow.objects.all(),
                fields=('user', 'following',)
            )
        ]

    def validate_following(self, value):
        if value == self.context.get('request').user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'You can not follow yourslef!'
            )
        return value
```

views.py

```
class FollowViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FollowSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        new_queryset = Follow.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return new_queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Use `SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', queryset=User.objects.all())`, then you can use the username in POST requests.

Comment: Use different serializers for create and read

Answer (score 0):

A `SlugRelatedField` allows to also perform a lookup when writing and thus retrieve in this case the user with the given username.

You thus can implement this as:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class FollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugField(
        read_only=True,
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    following = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        queryset=get_user_model().objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'following',)
        # …
    
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).